# How NOT to be Afraid of Using Glute-Ham Raise (GHR) Machine

Tags: bodybuilding, lower-back, hamstring, machine, glutes

*Some background: I've been into bodybuilding for a few years, but only 2 months ago I started to go to a proper gym with a proper trainer. For a full-month my trainer checked me up of my muscles, trainings, and such; then at the end of the session, he recommended me to train lower back and legs: the muscles which I rarely develop before.*

So I found out that GHR machine is very suitable to be incorporated in my training, plus many people find that it's very effective.

However, when I wanted to try it for the first time, there was this "uneasy feeling", I was scared to lean my body forward. Some bad thoughts appeared:

- What if the machine fall forward?
- What if I can't curl my leg and I'm stuck on the lay position?
- Did I position my leg correctly to not hurt or even break my bone?

People said GHR is one of a safest workout though. But because of those feelings, I'm kinda thinking otherwise.

**So how should I do to overcome these feelings?**

Comment: This is probably less of a question for the fitness.stackexchange and more of one for the psychology.stackexchange. They will probably bring up general techniques for overcoming fear such as exposure therapy. Typically fear comes from previous experiences, and to override those feelings, you slowly build up to the task you are afraid of doing. So in this scenario, perhaps have someone spot you, until you feel comfortable doing the movement by yourself.

Comment: Have someone qualified check your form to make sure you're being safe. Then have a buddy hold your hands as you lean forward so you don't fear falling, then try progressing to "no buddy in front, but an elastic around your shoulders", then to "no buddy, no elastic".